# React Native - state is returning null after setting state

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm very much new to react native currently i'm building small app for just getting an idea about this. I'm facing an issue in mapping the data from API. This is the json response returning from the api

`{"data":[{"digit":300,"countsum":"52"},{"digit":301,"countsum":"102"},{"digit":302,"countsum":"27"},{"digit":303,"countsum":"201"},{"digit":500,"countsum":"101"}]}`

When i tried to map this data i'm facing some issues. I stored the response from API to the state and when i tried to display the state data using `map` function it's showing the state value is null. This the code i tried till now

```
const [listdata, setListData] = useState(null)
useEffect(() => {
    // Run! Like go get some data from an API.
    getListData();
}, []);

const getListData = async () => {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@userToken")
    axios
        .get(constants.BASE_URL + "getlist?token=" +token)
        .then(response => setListData(response.data))
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
        listdata.map(item => <Text>{item.digit}</Text>)
  }
```

Comment: i dont see where are you storing data into `listData` ?

Comment: @Sakshi setListData(response.data)

Comment: Try console.log listdata at this stage, you will find that it is still null, in other words, the value of the updated value of the listdata:useSate will be ready after the render take place. You can make another function outside of the current one. then use useEffect with listdata to update your text views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this,

```
export default function ComponentName () {
const [listdata, setListData] = useState([])
useEffect(() => {
    // Run! Like go get some data from an API.
    getListData();
}, []);

const getListData = async () => {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@userToken")
    axios
        .get(constants.BASE_URL + "getlist?token=" +token)
        .then(response => setListData(response.data))
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
}

return (<>
        listdata.map(item => <Text>{item.digit}</Text>)
</>
);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait the fetch execution and later do the list map.

```
// wait for it
await axios
   .get(constants.BASE_URL + "getlist?token=" +token)
   .then(response => setListData(response.data))
   .catch(error => {
     console.log(error);
   });
   listdata.map(item => <Text>{item.digit}</Text>)
```

Comment: Still it showing Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: listdata is null

Comment: You shall use it like this: useState([]) // empty array

Answer (score 0):

If you want to map the data then do that inside return statement of your code ,like:

```
return(
{listData?listdata.map(item => return <Text>{item.digit}</Text>):""}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample of a meant in my comment above:

> Try console.log listdata at this stage, you will find that it is still
> null, in other words, the value of the updated value of the
> listdata:useSate will be ready after the render take place. You can
> make another function outside of the current one. then use useEffect
> with listdata to update your text views

```
const [listdata, setListData] = useState(null)

useEffect(() => makeRemoteRequest(), [listdata])


makeRemoteRequest = () => {
    const url = `your-url-of-data-here`;
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        setListData(res.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
       console.log(error)
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
const [listdata, setListData] = useState([])
useEffect(() => {
    // Run! Like go get some data from an API.
    getListData();
}, []);

const getListData = async () => {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@userToken")
    try {
        const dataResponse = await axios.get(constants.BASE_URL + "getlist?token=" +token);
        setListData(dataResponse.data || [] );
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

return (<>
    listdata.map(item => <Text>{item.digit}</Text>)
</>);
```